# copy passwd from linux to windows

Tags: passwords

Is it possible to copy login passwords from linux to windows, if I only have the linux password hash?

I believe this is fairly straight forward if you do not change OS, but is it possible cross platform?

Comment: Are you asking if you’re able to configure Linux to authenticate with your Windows username and password? Is the Windows machine connected to an Active Directory domain?

Comment: I have a number of user profiles created on linux. I would like to create local windows accounts with the same user/pw. It looks like windows uses a different hash algorithm to store pw and may even be machine specific?

Comment: It is entirely straightforward. I do this from time to time. Put the password in a Notepad file, move it to the other system, open with a Text editor and you are good to go. Encrypted passwords between different systems? No.

Comment: @PaulS. - Unless you link Linux, to an Active Directory domain, through IPA, what you want is impossible.  Windows and Linux cannot share usernames otherwise.  The two operating systems are not compatible with one another without a unified domain solution.

Comment: Well I found one site that claims windows stores pw as unsalted md4 hashes. So if I have the md4 hash of the pw I should be able to just overwrite the value in the registry? I'm not familiar with the windows registry, but I'm trying to see if i can find where its stored and if I md4 my known password does it match the stored value.

https://techdirectarchive.com/2020/10/09/windows-cached-credentials-how-does-cached-domain-logon-work/

Answer (score 1):

While it may be possible to do this via some hacked together decryption/recryption scheme, it is unlikely you'll be successful outside using a shared authentication framework such as LDAP/Active Directory.

That is, in fact, the correct way to do this: set up a shared centralized authentication system and use the accounts from this system to login on the various computers and OSes.